# Excel print combined cells

Tags: excel, printing, cells

Maybe a simple question but since I'm googling since 5 hours with no solution
I'll ask here.

Story:
I have a biiiig sheet with different data (like: company, adress, project ...).
That sheet is just for the data input. In a second sheet I have all the raw data
and made it shiny for my boss. At the bottom of the sheet, theres a big field with combined cells, where the "documentation/Information" should be inserted. Everything works... with smal data.

If the content of the information field extends 1 page, excel wont print it but cut at the end of that cell.

Is it possible to extend that field and print more than 1 page?

Comment: My experience has been to copy the text into a word document so formatting can be better applied, or embed the excel document into the word document for the raw data, and have the summary information pasted into the word document.  Excel, IMO, isn't the best choice for business letters, but it's great for raw data and charts.

Comment: In word I would have to draw the tables and stuff again, but I didnt get the excel information from an created object in excel into the word file (with something like a link or like that)

Comment: nevermind. found a pretty lame solution. I just enlarged the row :(

Comment: But even this runs into limits as display row height does have an upperlimit on the amount of data it displays in a single cell (409.5 pixels) or  about 28 lines of text. depending on font size etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Higher the value of the row height is a workaround.